Simultaneous diagonalisation and SVD
Let $M$ be a Hermitian matrix (real or complex) with eigenvalues $\pm1$, so that $M^2 = I$. Let us split it into blocks as follows:
$$M = \left(\begin{array}{cc} A_{k\times k} &B_{k\times m}\\ B^\dagger_{m\times k} & C_{m\times m} \end{array}\right).$$
I would like to diagonalise $A$ and $C$ and compute the SVD of (the not necessarily square) $B$.
However, due to the properties of $M$, the three matrices can be diagonalised by the same eigen/singular vectors:
$$ A = U \Lambda_A U^\dagger $$
$$ B = U \Lambda_B V^\dagger $$
$$ C = V \Lambda_C V^\dagger $$
where all the $\Lambda$ are diagonal. I would like to find good approximations of the unitaries $U$ and $V$ in the presence of small (machine-epsilon) errors.
So far, my strategy is to start either by diagonalising $A$ or $C$ or by computing the SVD of $B$, then to adjust the matrices to lift any degeneracies. However, numerical errors tend to amplify (e.g. if I diagonalise $A$, the best SVD approximation I can achieve for $B$ with the same $U$ will still have off-diagonal entries around $\sqrt\epsilon$, even though $M^2=I$ to within $\epsilon$). This means that I cannot resolve eigenvalues that are closer to each other than about $\sqrt\epsilon$. Therefore, I'd need an algorithm that takes all three equations into account simultaneously.

This makes no sense. In what way would the block-wise factorization work? In general, the eigenvalues of $A$ will not be among the ones from $M$. The eigenvector matrix for $M$ will not be block-diagonal, so your formulas should also contain the off-diagonal blocks of this matrix.

I don't want to diagonalise $M$, I want to diagonalise $A$ and $C$ and compute the SVD of $B$. However, it is possible to do this with shared unitaries (since e.g. $A$ and $BB^\dagger$ commute, this is the only place where the block structure of $M$ matters). I want a numerically stable way of finding these unitaries.
